# Git: File line ending (LF/CRLF)

Tags: git, android-studio, core.autocrlf

I use the git module inside the Android Studio to work with my repository. Some files are versioned without any changes and it says:

> Contents have differences only in line separators

[image]

After some searching I find out that the problem is the line ending character. My OS is Windows and the local files are CRLF, however the remote files are LF.

I tried to use EOL conversion in notepad++, but it was useless.
I don't have .gitattributes file.

I checked the config file and it was the `core.autocrlf` is true. I can't set it to false because I use both Mac and Windows.

I tried the `git config --global core.eol lf` and `git update-index --refresh`, but the problem is still there.

**I know there are lots of questions about LF-CRLF but they didn't work for me because I've already checked out and changed some of my files. So I need to commit my changed files.**

Comment: May I ask you: Which type of line ending does the remote repository have?  Is it `\n` (Linux) or `\r\n` (Windows)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's Linux